# Symfony2: Are Entity Assert Messages Escaped?

Tags: symfony, escaping, assert

If I define my Entity Assert like this:

```
$oEmailLengthAssert = new Assert\Length(array(
    'max'           => 255,
    'maxMessage'    => 'E-mail address cannot be longer than {{ limit }} characters length'
));
```

Looks like it is rendered by the Twig and all its output is escaped. But I'm still hesitating if the Assert message is escaped?

Comment: what do you mean by " if the Assert message is escaped?" ?

Comment: I mean is there a possibility that some special HTML chars will get rendered or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm asserting you're using the From component to use validation of entities, right?

If so, form uses (twig) views (symfony-standard uses twig at least).

Form can use different twig layouts (kindof themes), default is form_div_layout.html.twig:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig#L344

Which is escaped by default: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#escaper-extension